# ion-content scroll="true" not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

**Issue:** I have a simple add item form that adds a picture from the phone's album in a view.  For some reason, after adding ion-content scroll="true", the page still doesn't allow for scrolling.

Also, I've set $ionicScrollDelegate to refresh in the controller.  Thanks!

```
<ion-view title="Add Item">
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
      <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-content scroll="true">
    <!-- <ion-scroll direction="y" style="height: 800px;"> -->
      <ion-pane>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col text-center">
            <button class="button button-calm" ng-click="getPhoto()"><i class="ion-camera"></i> Select Photo</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list card" ng-show="item.pic">
          <div class="item">
            <img class="full-image" src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{item.pic}}">
          </div>
        </div>
        <form ng-submit="submitItem()" name="newItemForm" novalidate>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label" type="text">* Designer: </span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="item.designer" ng-required="true">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label" type="text">* Type/Collection: </span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="item.collection" ng-required="true">
          </label>
          <p ng-show="newItemForm.item.collection.$error.required">Type/Collection Required</p>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label" type="text">* Color: </span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="item.color" ng-required="true">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label" type="text">* Size: </span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="item.size" ng-required="true">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label" type="text">Material: </span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="item.material">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label" type="text">* Condition: </span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="item.condition" ng-required="true">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label" type="text">* Description: </span>
            <textarea type="text" ng-model="item.description" ng-required="true"></textarea>
          </label>
          <p ng-show="newItemForm.$invalid" class="warning">*Items must be filled in to Add Item</p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center">
              <button type="submit" class="button button-balanced" ng-disabled="newItemForm.$invalid"><i class="ion-plus"></i> Add Item</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </ion-pane>
    <!-- </ion-scroll> -->
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, you might want to check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30865306/ionic-pane-not-scrolling I think your `ion-pane` might be the cause

Comment: I might be wrong but I think it should be one or the other with `ion-content` and `ion-pane`, and not one inside the other. Like I said I may be wrong so if somebody could correct me

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  If I get rid of ion-pane, the page all of the ion-content disappears on focus of a form element for some reason.